# send commands to other buffers which can be EXWM

Tags: buffers, exwm

How can I send commands to other buffers which are EXWM, say, URxvt?

This works for generic emacs buffers:

```lisp
(with-current-buffer "local_machine.org" (insert "Hello"))
```

I want to send to urxvt keystrokes (`ls -la`), be able to execute commands as if I was in that buffer such as `balance-windows`

Comment: I have partially solved my task with an other approach, though it is not related to EXWM
```(shell)
(with-current-buffer "*shell*" (insert "echo 'rest'")
(comint-send-input))```

Comment: or ```(defun s (arg1 &optional shellbuffer)
(or shellbuffer (setq shellbuffer "*terminal*"))
  (with-current-buffer shellbuffer
    (insert arg1)
    (term-send-input)))``` for term